# Laravel 5.2 bind certain value from every result into array

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, query-builder

I have a query (using query builder) like below:

```
$results = DB::table('owner')
         ->join('pet', 'pet.owner_id', '=', 'owner.id')
         ->select('owner.*', 'pet.name AS pet_name')
         ->where('owner.name', 'John')
         ->get();

return response()->json($results);
```

and the response looks like:

```
{
 [
  "id" = 1,
  "name" = "John",
  "gender" = "M",
  "pet_name" = "Judy"
 ],
 [
  "id" = 1,
  "name" = "John",
  "gender" = "M",
  "pet_name" = "Nick"
 ],
}
```

I want only one result showing a owner's data with all his pets,
which would be like:

```
{
 [
  "id" = 1,
  "name" = "John",
  "gender" = "M",
  "pet_name" = ["Judy", "Nick"]
 ]
}
```

How can I do this with query builder?

Comment: `select('owner.*', 'GROUP_CONCAT(pet.name) AS pet_name')`

Comment: @Anant the result turned out to be `"pet_name" = "Judy, Nick"`, how can I make it an array rather than a single string separated by coma?

Comment: `$result['pet_name'] = explode(',',$result['pet_name'])` and then  `return response()->json($results);`